# Define 'api' traceback errors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to search YouTube for videos using YouTube v3 API in Python with the requirements in the code, but I'm getting this error.
[image]

How can I prevent this from happening? This code is from Google too. You can edit the code on the Google website [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22location%22%3A%22United%20States%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A5%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22Programming%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22relevanceLanguage%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22safeSearch%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22videoDimension%22%3A%22any%22%2C%22videoDuration%22%3A%22any%22%7D). I'm a total noob at this so if you have any information I must know for the future, please do say so. Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.search.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():

    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
    
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

         # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    
    
    request = api.youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        location="United States",
        maxResults=5,
        order="date",
        q="programming",
        regionCode="US",
        relevanceLanguage="en",
        safeSearch="none",
        videoDimension="any",
        videoDuration="any"


        
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## error number two

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah your code may be from google but you have renamed something.

All your calls need to go though the YouTube serivce object

```
 youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

Yet you are calling it using api

```
request = api.youtube.search().list(
```

it should be

```
request = youtube.search().list(
```

Check the code from google again and becameful when you rename things if you don't understand what there used for.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.search.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        location="United States",
        maxResults=5,
        order="date",
        q="Programming",
        regionCode="US",
        relevanceLanguage="en",
        safeSearch="none",
        videoDimension="any",
        videoDuration="any"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Error number 2

You need to check the parameters you are sending remove location thats not a valid location

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found that I was stupid and added the API part on line 33, but when I run it and get the authorization code, it comes up with this. I also experienced this error before.
[2nd error](https://imgur.com/uQqFpKM)

Comment: the location you are sending isnt valid.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I forgot to read all of that! Thanks so much for your help. I'll read more next time.